# Can I use the external nor flash as program memory and data storage at the same time?

Tags: spi, data-storage, flash-memory, lpc

I am using lpc54016 on a custom board with winbond w25q32jvss as external SPI flash memory. Can I use winbond w25q32jvss for storing the code memory as well as store some data for my application at the same time?

Comment: It is possible but very impractical (and you probably tear off the memory block(s) quite fast).

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Just out of my guts: Data storage may be problematic as the number of write cycles may be limited. Look it up in the datasheet.